# Помогите решить задачку на python

Tags: python

Напишите программу, которая будет разрезать большую прямоугольную область на N×N одинаковых прямоугольных областей. Области задаются четырьмя координатами: минимальной широтой, минимальной долготой, максимальной широтой, максимальной долготой.

При выводе области должны быть упорядочены по возрастанию минимальной широты, а в случае равных широт - по возрастанию минимальной долготы.

Гарантируется, что все числа во входных данных положительны.

У меня не сходится максимальная долгота.
Вот часть кода которая считает:

```
dlat = (maxlat - minlat) / N
dlon = (maxlon - minlon) / N

    for i in range(N):
        for j in range(N):
            nminlat = minlat + dlat * i
            nmaxlat = minlat + dlat * (i + 1)
            nminlon = minlon + dlon * j
            nmaxlon = maxlon + dlon * (j + 1)
            print(nminlat, nminlon, nmaxlat, nmaxlon)
```

По i перебирается широта, по j перебирается долгота

Comment: ну так и назови переменные вместо i и j так, чтобы было понятно, что там широта и долгота. А то послезавтра откроешь сам свой же код и не будешь знать что какая переменная означает

Comment: что значит "не сходится"? что на входе, что на выходе, что должно быть?

Comment: на вход подается мин. широта, мин. долгота, макс, широта, макс. долгота и количество частей на которые мы делим, на выходе должны получить те же значения в том же порядке для каждого получившегося прямоугольника(кроме количества частей, разумеется). у меня не сходится именно макс. долгота, программа проверку не проходит, у них другое значение.
пример ввода:
41.173 77.23 42.17 79.004
2

Comment: ну я вижу, например, что вычисления разные. Должны быть или все 4 подобные, или 2 и 2

Comment: Все, спасибо, я просто идиот. в строке nmaxlon = maxlon + dlon * (j + 1), должно быть (j-1).

Answer (score 0):

Ошибка в строке `nmaxlon = maxlon + dlon * (j + 1)`, должно быть `(j - 1)`

Comment: отметьте закрытым